# 16GB M1 Mac running slow after couple days of usage

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance, virtual-memory, resources

After a fresh restart, everything is smooth. During the next couple of days of regular usage of the system, a problem of responsiveness gradually increases, until you can count a full second between you swiping a desktop and the system actually responding to the gesture.

I've tried reducing memory pressure by closing high memory apps, but it doesn't help at all.

[Video demonstration here](https://youtu.be/4808ncnbSEA).

Comment: What does the CPU tab in Activity Monitor show?

Comment: @nohillside no significant usage by any app

Comment: Also, what about the swiping behaviorist shown in the video worries you? Do you have some more specific examples of „slow“ or „lagging“?

Comment: While I don't know the exact issue that you're running into, I tend to start seeing issues with my MacBook Pro after an uptime of 25+ days. What kind of memory usage are you seeing, how many VM files do you see in /var/vm/ ?

Comment: And Monterey has some known issues with memory not getting freed (e.g. when using „find“ in Finder), which could explain the memory pressure you see

Comment: @nohillside I'm not worried, I'm frustrated by the 1 second delay for the system to respond to my swipe.

Comment: @ErniePC12 there's only a single sleepimage file of 1.07GB

Comment: @Birowsky My only other thought is that you might have software running under Rosetta?

Comment: @Birowsky Just to help you diagnose this - when I see the lag you're describing for us in the video, I see absolutely no indication of that being caused by memory pressure at all. I would stop concentrating on the memory situation and look at other causes for this - I very much doubt that it has anything to do with memory at all.

Comment: @jksoegaard that indeed turned out to be the case. I've found that the issue is fixed by restarting the Dock process. Now I wish I knew what exactly corrupts Dock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with the Dock process. It's fixed by restarting it with:

```
killall -KILL Dock
```

Now I wish I knew what corrupts it in the first place.

Comment: You could delete the Dock preference plists and 'start again'. I seem to recall that some other features fall under the Dock process, but I can't remember what.

Comment: @benwiggy what do you mean by "Dock preference plists"?

Comment: In the user Library/Preferences folder, files like com.apple.Dock.plist and the matching .db file. Then log out/in or restart.

Answer (score 1):

macOS Monterey is known to have massive memory leaks. The root cause is not yet quite clear. One memory leak I know of is that, when searching from Finder, the memory allocated for the search is not released any more.

Check the activity monitor for high memory usage of any process and kill that process.

Other memory leaks I've come across are:

- Mail app hogs memory. Here it's enough to quit and restart Mail.
- Spotlight search in Mail causes issues with symptoms being that no more matching results are found. Then kill process `corespotlightd`  (will restart automatically).
- Using Sidecar causes process `WindowServer` to hog a lot of memory. Seems a reboot is required to fix this.